# javascript isPresent always returning TRUE (Protractor)

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

So, I am accessing an application. There are `multiple employee records`. However, there are no duplicate records. I am deleting an employee record and then trying to verify that the employee record has actually deleted. I am trying to find the employee name using **xpath** and using `isPresent` function. The problem is that though the employee record is deleted the output is always returning

```
Employee present: true
```

Here is the piece of code that I am using:

```
it('Delete Employee', function() {
        login_page.enterUsername(browser.params.username);
        login_page.enterPassword(browser.params.password);
        var employeelist_page = login_page.clickLoginButton();
        var greetings = employeelist_page.greetingText();
        expect(greetings).toContain('Hello');
        var empName = employeelist_page.getEmployeeName(Master Shifu);
        empName.getText().then(function(text) {
            console.log('Empoyee record to be deleted, found: ' + text);
        });
        employeelist_page.getEmployee(Master Shifu).click();
        //element(by.id('bDelete')).click();
        employeelist_page.clickDeleteButton();
        //browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), 5000, "Alert is not getting present :(")
                browser.switchTo().alert().accept().then(function(){
                    var employeelist_page1 = require('../page/employeelist_page.js');
                    employeelist_page1.getEmployee(Master Shifu).isPresent().then(function(isPresent){
                        if(isPresent){
                            console.log('Employee present: true');
                        } else {
                            console.log('Employee present: false');
                        }
                    });
                });

    });
```

Here is the HTML sample of employee list:

```
<ul id="employee-list">
<li class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-class="employee.id == selectedEmployee.id && 'active'" ng-dblclick="editEmployee()" ng-click="selectEmployee(employee)" ng-repeat="employee in employees"> Tianna2 Jenkins </li>
<li class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-class="employee.id == selectedEmployee.id && 'active'" ng-dblclick="editEmployee()" ng-click="selectEmployee(employee)" ng-repeat="employee in employees"> Anjali McClure </li>
<li class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-class="employee.id == selectedEmployee.id && 'active'" ng-dblclick="editEmployee()" ng-click="selectEmployee(employee)" ng-repeat="employee in employees"> John Snow </li>
<li class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-class="employee.id == selectedEmployee.id && 'active'" ng-dblclick="editEmployee()" ng-click="selectEmployee(employee)" ng-repeat="employee in employees"> Cole Prohaska </li>
<li class="ng-scope ng-binding" ng-class="employee.id == selectedEmployee.id && 'active'" ng-dblclick="editEmployee()" ng-click="selectEmployee(employee)" ng-repeat="employee in employees"> Annetta Hessel </li>
```

**Here is the output:**

*`Empoyee record to be deleted, found: Master Shifu`

Employee present: true

Comment: Any chance to share with us HTML? When manually execute this step, what is the result? The record is deleted, or not?
try to console.log(isPresent()) before IF statement. Also, log his type, value, content and etc.

Comment: @Zhivko.Kostadinov, updated the question and added sample HTML

Comment: Super. What happening with debugging? Share with us the result of logging, which I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: After click `delete`, check the HTML code of that employee is also removed from the HTML DOM Tree?  Maybe the deleted employee just be hidden, not removed from DOM Tree.

Comment: No. The deleted employee is removed. I have checked. It’s not hidden

Answer (score 0):

Try the script as below. The reason I added .then function is that the script in the then block will execute after the clickdeleteButton action is completed. Your script to check if the element is present after delete might be executing before its been deleted.

```
employeelist_page.clickDeleteButton().then(function() {
        //browser.switchTo().alert().accept();
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), 5000, "Alert is not getting present :(")
                browser.switchTo().alert().accept().then(function(){
                    var employeelist_page1 = require('../page/employeelist_page.js');
                    employeelist_page1.getEmployee(Master Shifu).isPresent().then(function(isPresent){
                        if(isPresent){
                            console.log('Employee present: true');
                        } else {
                            console.log('Employee present: false');
                        }
                    });
                });
})
```